How can one make a visible light bulb that works through cyclotron radiation?
I figure that I first start with a charged particle accelerator. Let's say we can make this from electromagnets arranged in a circular ring in the XY plane with a magnetic field $B$, perpendicular to the XY plane pointing in the $\hat{k}$ direction or +z axis.
On Wikipedia, the power of cyclotron radiation for a single electron is given by the following equation, where $E$ is energy, $t$ is time, $\sigma_{t}$ is the Thomson cross section (total, not differential), $B$ is the magnetic field strength, $v$ is the velocity perpendicular to the magnetic field, $c$ is the speed of light and $\mu_{0}$ is the permeability of free space
\begin{equation}
     -\frac{dE}{dt}=\frac{\sigma_{t}B^{2}v^{2}}{c\mu_{0}}
\end{equation}
I desire to create visible white light with a frequency spectrum that is as perfectly uniform as possible, I would need the electrons to emit an energy $E=\hbar f$ per unit time, where $f$ is the frequency of the light I need. Let's say we divide up the visible light frequency spectrum into say N discrete parts such that $\Delta f=f_{i+1}-f_{i}$ is indistinguishable to the naked eye. We would then need to sum this up, $\Sigma_{i}^{N}E_{i}=E_{\mathrm{whitelight}}$. But we need the intensity to be as bright as a typcial lightbulb, so we need like 400 or so lumens after looking online for some typical values. This is where I am a bit confused, I see that lumens per watt are listed for an incandescent light bulb or LED, etc. but since I'm making my own cyclotron lightbulb, so I am unsure where to go from here to figure out the rest of the calculation.
I need to set the power equal to the right hand side of the cyclotron radiation equation, so I will want to choose a powerful magnetic field produced by a permanent magnet like those neodymium ones that are around $1$ Tesla or so. I am also unfamiliar with the Thomson cross section and how to get that as well.
In summary, I want to be able to do this project in a makerspace or in my garage one day and gather materials to construct it. I also want to make an instructbles of how to do this for everyone. Can anyone here help?

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/343292/123208

"a visible light bulb" what you aim for cannot be a light bulb in the definition of "light bulb" https://www.britannica.com/technology/lightbulb

I should rephrase, I want to use the workings of cyclotron radiation to serve the function of a lightbulb, or I want to to make a cyclotron emit visible white light. How can I do this in a manner that is doable in my garage or makerspace? Bonus: How can I make it compact like a light bulb?
